# Want to store view detail page product id into session

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a recent visited product section. In view detail when user enter the product id will be `$_GET['pid'];` Now wanted to store it into `$_SESSION['views'];` Now it will be store into session. Then it need to be display as an array because it need to be put in Select query of product then it will be display in while loop.

```
$_SESSION['views']=$_GET['pid'];
```

Now when I enter into another product view detail page. The session will have 1, 
Then in Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `property` WHERE id=$_SESSION['views']
```

But it needs to be while and display in loop.
After 7 products visit The first one will be removed and latest one should be insert into the last of session which will display new record.

Comment: Have you tried using an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$_SESSION['views'] = array();
```

Then add new product

```
function addProduct($product)
{
    $_SESSION['views'][] = $product;
    if (count($_SESSION['views']) > 7) {
        $removedElement = array_shift($_SESSION['views']);
    }
}
```

Query

```
SELECT * FROM `property` WHERE id in <?= implode($_SESSION['views']) ?>
```

If you need more Object oriented approach, look at SPL.

Comment: It displays me Array ( [views] => Array ( ) )

Answer (score 0):

If you want show all 7 products, you should make query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `property` WHERE id IN ($productList)
```

and $productList should be ID's of products, separated by comma, like this:

```
$productList = join(',', $_SESSION['views']);
```

now you need $_SESSION['views'] to be ab array:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['views'])) {
    // add new element
    $_SESSION['views'][] = $_GET['pid'];
    // remove old elements
    if (count($_SESSION['views'] > 7)) array_shift($_SESSION['views']);
} else {
    // initialize an array
    $SESSION['views'] = array($_GET['pid']);
}
```

Comment: what is the $productList where from it is coming? @user3392550

Comment: Warning: join(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\wamp\www\

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: views in C:\wamp\www\

Comment: you should initialize your $_SESSION['views'] array first (see third part of code), then you can evaluate $productList, which would be just pid's separated by comma, and it used at IN part of sql query